# is there a better way for this method?

Tags: php, mysqli

i am trying to make a code that will work like the one below, but i need it to fetch data only once because my code below is fetching more than once and i am afraid it will slow down the server. is there a better way to do the same with the one below. basically the code below will put the list from database into its own div category.

```
<div class="popular-video">
<h2>Popular</h2>
    <ul>
    <?php 

        global $connection;
        $sexy = "sexy";
        $query = "SELECT `videoname`,`username`,`videourl`,`uploaddate`,`duration`,`views`,`tags` FROM `videolist` WHERE `tags` = ? ";
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$sexy);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            $stmt->bind_result($videoname,$username,$videourl,$uploaddate,$duration,$views,$tags);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                if($username == 'ichigo'){
                echo "
                        <a href='video.php?watch=$videourl'>
                        <li>
                            <div class='leftside'>
                                <img src='' width='100%' height='100%' style='background-color: blue;' >                    
                            </div>

                            <div class='rightside'>
                                <h4>$videoname</h4>
                                <p>$username</p>
                                <p>$views views</p>
                                <p>$duration</p>                    
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        </a>
                ";                      
                }

            }
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="subcription-video">
<h2>Subcription</h2>
    <ul>
    <?php
        global $connection;
        $sexy = "sexy";
        $query = "SELECT `videoname`,`username`,`videourl`,`uploaddate`,`duration`,`views` FROM `videolist` WHERE `tags` = ? ";
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$sexy);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            $stmt->bind_result($videoname,$username,$videourl,$uploaddate,$duration,$views);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo "
                        <a href='video.php?watch=$videourl'>
                        <li>
                            <div class='leftside'>
                                <img src='' width='100%' height='100%' style='background-color: blue;' >                    
                            </div>

                            <div class='rightside'>
                                <h4>$videoname</h4>
                                <p>$username</p>
                                <p>$views views</p>
                                <p>$duration</p>                    
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        </a>
                ";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="related-video-by-subcription">
<h2>Related-Video</h2>
    <ul>
    <?php
        global $connection;
        $sexy = "sexy";
        $query = "SELECT `videoname`,`username`,`videourl`,`uploaddate`,`duration`,`views` FROM `videolist` WHERE `tags` = ? ";
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$sexy);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            $stmt->bind_result($videoname,$username,$videourl,$uploaddate,$duration,$views);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo "
                        <a href='video.php?watch=$videourl'>
                        <li>
                            <div class='leftside'>
                                <img src='' width='100%' height='100%' style='background-color: blue;' >                    
                            </div>

                            <div class='rightside'>
                                <h4>$videoname</h4>
                                <p>$username</p>
                                <p>$views views</p>
                                <p>$duration</p>                    
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        </a>
                ";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think a couple of queries will affect your server speed that much.

Comment: there is 9 queries similar to this one, and it will slow down the server if i do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function and call that function in your HTML.

```
function foo() {
    global $connection;
    $sexy = "sexy";
    $query = "SELECT `videoname`,`username`,`videourl`,`uploaddate`,`duration`,`views` FROM `videolist` WHERE `tags` = ? ";

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$sexy);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($videoname, $username, $videourl, $uploaddate, $duration, $views);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "<a href='video.php?watch=$videourl'>
                    <li>
                        <div class='leftside'>
                            <img src='' width='100%' height='100%' style='background-color: blue;' >                    
                        </div>

                        <div class='rightside'>
                            <h4>$videoname</h4>
                            <p>$username</p>
                            <p>$views views</p>
                            <p>$duration</p>                    
                        </div>
                    </li>
                  </a>";
         }
    }
}
```

Then just call the function where you want it.

```
<div class="popular-video">
    <h2>Popular</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php foo(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i meant to call the query once and but the fetch will be placed into its own categories

Comment: Then just store all the results in an array.

Comment: once i call the array outside its while function it only show one of the data

Comment: Probably because you are overriding the previous value each time your while loop loops.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your business logic from presentation logic.

And you can call *$stmt->fetch_all()* and save the result in a variable and then use this variable in your loops.